# Library built with Webpack 5 not tree shakeable

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules, webpack-5

I have a React component library that is built by webpack 5.75.0. The library exports 2 components:

```
// src/index.ts
export { default as ComponentA } from "components/ComponentA";
export { default as ComponentB } from "components/ComponentB";
```

A simple CRA app uses this library and imports only `ComponentA`. But when analyzing the bundle I see that `ComponentB`'s dependencies are in it and have not been tree-shaken.

The parent app is just a CRA app with no config overrides. Tree shaking works there for other modules (MUI, lodash-es, etc), so the problem is with the my library.

I seem to have followed all requirements: in my package.json I do have

```
"sideEffects": false,
"main": "lib/index.js",
"module": "lib/index.js",
```

Here's my babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current", modules: false } }],
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        runtime: "automatic",
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        regenerator: true,
        useESModules: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

And here's my webpack config:

```
const config = {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: false,
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "lib"),
    filename: "index.js",
    module: true,
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    //...
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    //...
  },
  externals: [
    "react",
    "react-dom",
  ],
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

But still, the `ComponentB`'s dependencies are showing up in the bundle of the CRA app that uses this library.

Am I missing something? Is there some official example of how to configure tree-shaking library with webpack 5?

Thanks.

**UPD**: Resolved by using Rollup ¯_(ツ)_/¯

**P.S.** My question relates to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743562/how-to-create-tree-shakable-library-with-webpack), but since 2021 it's become possible to build ES modules with Webpack 5.